# Developing Java, C#, and .NET on the same machine

Tags: c#, java

I found a couple of threads that touch on development of C#/Java apps but I don't think they go along with this question.

I was wondering if it was a good idea to be developing Java, C#, and .NET applications on one computer. That means there's ## .NET versions installed at one time, ### Java JRE's installed at any given time. Is that a good idea? I'm just thinking there is eventually going to be a huuuuuuuge conflict and the computer is going to say "I'm done. Poof".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fine.

If you have any modern system, you're already going to have all of these runtimes installed.  Having the SDK installed doesn't add any overhead unless you're actually using it, so there is no problem.  Both .NET and Java strive to allow multiple runtimes installed side-by-side, without conflicts.

Go ahead, develop away, and enjoy!

Comment: Wow. I think that's the fastest I've ever had things answered on here. Like 10 minutes later and 7 answers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, C# targets .NET, so there's no conflict there.  You can certainly have multiple .NET CLRs side by side on the same machine, and multiple versions of Visual Studio if you need to target the 1.x CLRs.

However, there is one thing to watch out for.  .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 include updates to the 2.0 CLR, so some care is required when developing for 2.0 on a machine that has 3.x installed -- it won't go poof, but you may need to watch out for compatibility issues.  This particularly problematic when developing for 3.5 RTM on a machine with 3.5 SP1 installed, as Visual Studio will *not* warn you of SP1/RTM compatibility issues in this case!

Comment: What is the care involved (other than remembering to set the target framework)?  Even if you're developing for 2.0 applications, the security updates people should have installed give you the same updates to the 2.0 framework as the 3.5 framework install...

Comment: Hmm, you're right, this is probably no longer an issue now that 3.5 SP1 has been around for so long.  It certainly *was* an issue a year or two back when the 3.0 SPs still weren't by any means universal; I guess that just made me over-cautious **grin**.

Answer (score 2):

> *I'm just thinking there is eventually going to be a huuuuuuuge conflict*

There should be no problem as long as you know how things work.

The main problem may be your machine resources ( CPU/RAM/HD etc )

I have had java 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 in the same machine without a single problem. I understand the same applies to .net

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like this ever happened to me. I'm studying and I have to do many different kinds of projects. I had about 6 or 7 versions of java installed. Net frameworks from 1.1 to 4.0. VS 2008 and 2010b2. There is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You could have many different versions of the .net framework and Visual Studio installed side-by-side, and you can also develop for different .net frameworks in VS2010 and VS2008.

As for the Java JRE's, I'll leave that part up to the JavaGurus...

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of what might cause your computer to say "Poof". Mine has yet to say that and I run both dev environments on mine.

Answer (score 0):

.NET code relies on the.NET Framework, 1.1, 2.0, 3.5 and even 4.0 run side by side with no big issues, the IDE also allows targeting your applications to specific versions of the framework. Not certain about Java's tolerance for multiple JRE versions, but 1.1, 2.x, 3.5 and 4.0 all behave just fine on a single machine.